# How to use aggregate functions on the time of a datetime column with Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datetime, eloquent

I have the following SQL table :

```
|---------------------------------------------|
| LESSONS                                     |
|-----------------------|---------------------|
| BEGIN_DATE (DateTime) | END_DATE (DateTime) |
|-----------------------|---------------------|
|  2019-04-22 10:00:00  | 2019-04-22 12:00:00 |
|  2019-04-23 09:00:00  | 2019-04-23 10:00:00 |
```

Using Laravel Eloquent, I want to get the minimum hour of all lessons for the `BEGIN_DATE` column, and the maximum hour from the `END_DATE` column.
In this case, I would like to have `09:00:00` for the minimal hour, and `12:00:00` for the maximal hour.

I first tried `Lesson::min('begin_date')` and `Lesson::max('end_date')` but it obviously returned the minimal and maximal DateTime, not Time.

I also tried

```
Lesson::select('select cast(begin_datetime as time)')
    ->where('season_id', $this->id)->min(time);
```

but I get an SQL error:

> 'COLUMN NOT FOUND` for the time alias.

Also, I would prefer a solution only with Eloquent, using no `SQL`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$data = Lesson::selectRaw(
            'min(TIME(begin_date)) as min_time, max(TIME(end_date)) as max_time'
        )
        ->first()
        ->toArray();
```

This should return something like this:

```
dd($data);
```

> ```
> => [
>      "min_time" => "09:00:00",
>      "max_time" => "12:00:00",
>    ]
> ```

I'd also like to see an Eloquent approach on this (tried but failed lol). I Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.